# Can “take”, “took”, and “would take” all be correct in “as long as I ___ care of it”?

Tags: word-choice, conditional-constructions, exam-questions

> She said I could borrow her camera as long as I ___ care of it.
>
> Take / Took / would take.

We had this question answered in class and I think my teacher's answer was incorrect. (as he states that only “took” is right)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> She said I could borrow her camera as long as I took care of it.

seems most natural to me of the three alternatives in the question. I would be more inclined to say

> She said **that** I could borrow her camera as long as I took care of it.

but then my personal style tends toward the wordy.

Using "take" simply does not agree in tense. "would take" is possible, but I think awkward.